# Trying to nest Text components with different font properties inside another Text component. In one case, the line height cuts some of the text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I have a React Native application and I am trying to create a sentence where the different words have different styles, so I created a Text component and tried nesting other Text components with different styles inside of it. For example this works fine:

```
        <Text>
            <HeaderText2>Hello</HeaderText2>
            <HeaderText6>From</HeaderText6>
            <HeaderText2>The Other Side</HeaderText2>
        </Text>
```

And the result is:

[image]

However, if I swap the components so that the component with smaller line-height and font-size is first, it breaks somehow and nothing gets rendered.

```
        <Text>
            <HeaderText6>Hello</HeaderText6>
            <HeaderText2>From</HeaderText2>
            <HeaderText6>The Other Side</HeaderText6>
        </Text>
```

And this is how my HeaderText2 and HeaderText6 styled components look like:

```
const HeaderText2 = styled.Text`
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 39px;
`;

const HeaderText6 = styled.Text`
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
`;
```

Anyone have any clue why this might be happening? It's important to remember that this is React Native, so there might be some React Native shenanigans happening. When I delete the line-height of both components, it works fine but I want the line-height of the component with bigger line-height to take precedence and not be without line-height.

Answer (score 0):

Here are **Three solutions**

1. try out giving the same line-height to headerText6.
   Like this:

   ```
   const HeaderText2 = styled.Text`
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 39px;
    `;

    const HeaderText6 = styled.Text`
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 39px;
    `;
   ```
2. you could wrap all 3 texts in View container and give that container a flexdirection : 'row',
   like this:

   ```
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
         <HeaderText6>Hello</HeaderText6>
         <HeaderText2>From</HeaderText2>
         <HeaderText6>The Other Side</HeaderText6>
      </View>
   ```
3. you could remove line heights from header2 and header6 and give line-height to container Text
   like this:

   ```
    <containerText >
        <HeaderText6>Hello</HeaderText6>
        <HeaderText2>From</HeaderText2>
        <HeaderText6>The Other Side</HeaderText6>
    </containerText >

    const containerText = styled.Text`
    line-height: 39px;
    `;
   const HeaderText2 = styled.Text`
    font-size: 30px;
    `;
    const HeaderText6 = styled.Text`
    font-size: 12px;
    `;
   ```